# Accessing Android MainActivity "layout"

Tags: android, xamarin

Access the Xamarin Android MainActivity "layout" property from a different class.

I am trying to use Snackbar from a different class than MainActivity, however the "layout" property is not available. I have tried passing the MainActivity activity to the class, but "layout" is still not listed. I know that it is associated with the View, but I don't see it listed either. I have looked at numerous other properties associated with the activity, trying to find it.

```
Snackbar.Make(layout, "The xxx", Snackbar.LengthIndefinite)
    .SetAction("Ok", v => App.ExitApp())
    .Show();
```

I need to access the property to enable Snackbar. I expect to find a way to reference it.

Comment: Put a xamarin tag on these in the future.  Most readers in Android are Java/Kotlin programmers and won't know how to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Having passed in mainActivity, I was able to do this to get the layout.

```
var layout = mainActivity.Window.DecorView.RootView;

Snackbar.Make(layout, rationale, Snackbar.LengthIndefinite)
    .SetAction("OK", v => mainDeviceActivity.RequestPermissions(requiredpermission, App.currentPermission))
    .Show();
```